# Position: fixed and transform - how to return normal fixed behavior?

Tags: html, css, css-position, transform

I use `transform: translateZ(0);` as a mobile fix (I need to render a div constantly).
But `transform` creates another context and now my `fixed` div's height depends on parent height, not viewport height, as it was without `transform`.

I need `transform`, but I need a normal `fixed` behavior too. What should I do?

Comment: Please explain exactly why you need to use `translateZ(0)`.

Comment: `translateZ(0)` forces Chrome Android to redraw div properly. It allows div to have proper height when Chrome Android address bar appears or hides

Comment: Using `translateZ` on a fixed positioned element is a no-go. I have added a possible solution to your problem tho.

Answer (score 0):

There were alot of bug reports on Chrome about this "issue". I have encountered the same problem myself when writing a sticky plugin, but it turns out this is actually normal behaviour. This is because `transform` uses it's own coordinate system according to the [W3 specs](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-transforms-1/#transform-rendering). Basically, the element gets a fixed position relative to it's own fixed position. Unfortunately, there's nothing you can do about this.

**Possible solution**

A way to solve your problem is to give the "sticky" element an `absolute` position - relative to the document. Then reposition the element with JavaScript. Something along the lines of:

```
var element = document.getElementById('element');

window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
    requestAnimationFrame(setTop);
});

function setTop() {
    element.style.top = window.pageYOffset;
}
```

This way the element behaves as if it has a fixed position, while you're still able to use the `transform` property without any problems.